# Search string occurrence and display directory wise count

Tags: grep

We have a error log directory structure wherein we store all errors log files for a particular day in datewise directories -

```
errorbackup/20150629/errorlogFile3453123.log.xml
errorbackup/20150629/errorlogFile5676934.log.xml
errorbackup/20150629/errorlogFile9812387.log.xml
errorbackup/20150628/errorlogFile1097172.log.xml
errorbackup/20150628/errorlogFile1908071_log.xml
errorbackup/20150627/errorlogFile5675733.log.xml
errorbackup/20150627/errorlogFile9452344.log.xml
errorbackup/20150626/errorlogFile6363446.log.xml
```

I want to search for a particular string in the error log file and get the output such that I will get directory wise search result of a count of that string's occurrence. For example grep "blahblahSQLError" should output something like-

```
20150629:0
20150628:0
20150627:1
20150626:1
```

This is needed because we fixed some errors in one of the release and I want to make sure that there are no occurrences of that error since the day it was deployed to Prod. Also note that there are thousands of error log files created every day. Each error log file is created with a random number in its name to ensure uniqueness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure the filenames of the log files will not contain any "odd" characters or newlines then something like the following should work.

```
for dir in errorbackup/*; do
    printf '%s:%s\n' "${dir#*/}" "$(grep -l blahblahSQLError "$dir/"*.xml | wc -l)"
done
```

If they can have unexpected names then you would need to use multiple calls to `grep` and count the matching files manually I believe. Something like this.

```
for dir in errorbackup/*; do
    _dcount=0;
    for log in "$dir"/*.xml; do
        grep -l blahblahSQLError "$log" && _dcount=$((_dcount + 1));
    done
done
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Etan. The first one does not work for me. I guess the number of opening and closing double quotes are not matching. The second one gives error "syntax error near unexpected token `do'". I ran both these commands by entering it as a one-liner command as I cannot run it as a script.

Comment: The first one has a typo. I'm fixing it. If you need a one-liner of the second one you need a semi-colon in `_dcount=0;` and one in `)); done`. I'll add those also.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
for dir in errorbackup/*
do
    awk -v dir="${dir##*/}" -v OFS=':' '/blahblahSQLError/{c++} END{print dir, c+0}' "$dir"/*
done
```

There's probably a cuter way to do it with `find` and `xargs` to avoid the loop and you could certainly do it all within one `awk` command but life's too short....